# Какие параметры передать для POST запроса по решению капчи Python

Tags: python, requests

Час добрый
Не знаком с использованием post запросов в python для решения подобных задач. Ниже распишу подробности, пожалуйста объясните какие данные нужно передать в post запросе, так же просьба, напишите код этого запроса
Суть следующая: во время смены пароля от аккаунта в почте rambler требуется ввести капчу. Решение капчи сделал через сервис, получая в ответ токен решения, но каким образом его отправлять я не представляю. Все работает на python + selenium + requests
Блок с капчей находится в следующем виде:

```
<iframe src="https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/captcha/v1/9f58d19/static/hcaptcha-checkbox.html#id=1sruemy18uwp&amp;host=id.rambler.ru&amp;sentry=true&amp;reportapi=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.hcaptcha.com&amp;recaptchacompat=off&amp;custom=false&amp;hl=ru&amp;tplinks=on&amp;sitekey=322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460&amp;theme=light" title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge" tabindex="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-hcaptcha-widget-id="1sruemy18uwp" data-hcaptcha-response="" style="width: 303px; height: 78px; overflow: hidden;">
    #document
</iframe>
<textarea id="h-captcha-response-1sruemy18uwp" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

При решении капчи отслеживая события в инструментах разработчика (использую гугл хром) происходит 1 post запрос:

```
Headers => General

Request URL: https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha/E0_eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoiUFBvbU0vUXJjVVpOenlHOENvSVlpOEVCK2RwSElDU1IrVlk5V1QxNXRTU3RwRWtkcGVmZ2MvVlB6R1phUmlINmtMMkU1SSs3MTZwOTFyUXB2aTlsa29FV0R2MHg1bGNuMyttVVZQL3FBay82RnptU29IK255OXdRVXlsN292aittdkZCRVJISWREdVhpaTdXWEtYRDhIVFBtRGxYUmRJL2lYaWtrMU16QzRZY1Rub2FMOFJPRjJnTmdzaW50T29tZm5xT3NGcjdFbTNyRUR1ZktDV0FWb05IVk5KNHFxeWw2R1M2RlBGQ2hTYVgxTDJ6SGlSR0pXaXhYRE8zay9IMC9BeG1HQTY5S2wzWUNEN0drdz09MVNFV2dFVStheXQ5YXVvWiJ9.G6z8gXvWYoUV_KZAnP8SqWwHMac0B7lnL1R8q9P28Tg?s=322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
```

Ссылка содержит следующий вид: [https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha/{токен](https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha/%7B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD) решенной капчи}?s={ключ сайта}\

```
Request headers 

:authority: hcaptcha.com
:method: POST
:path: /checkcaptcha/E0_eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoiUFBvbU0vUXJjVVpOenlHOENvSVlpOEVCK2RwSElDU1IrVlk5V1QxNXRTU3RwRWtkcGVmZ2MvVlB6R1phUmlINmtMMkU1SSs3MTZwOTFyUXB2aTlsa29FV0R2MHg1bGNuMyttVVZQL3FBay82RnptU29IK255OXdRVXlsN292aittdkZCRVJISWREdVhpaTdXWEtYRDhIVFBtRGxYUmRJL2lYaWtrMU16QzRZY1Rub2FMOFJPRjJnTmdzaW50T29tZm5xT3NGcjdFbTNyRUR1ZktDV0FWb05IVk5KNHFxeWw2R1M2RlBGQ2hTYVgxTDJ6SGlSR0pXaXhYRE8zay9IMC9BeG1HQTY5S2wzWUNEN0drdz09MVNFV2dFVStheXQ5YXVvWiJ9.G6z8gXvWYoUV_KZAnP8SqWwHMac0B7lnL1R8q9P28Tg?s=322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 14908
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: https://newassets.hcaptcha.com
referer: https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36
```

Пробовал делать следующий запрос но в selenium ничего не изменилось:

```
post = f'https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha/{g_response}?s={site_key}'
requests.post(post)
```

Постарался максимально подробно описать проблему, скажите если нужно что-то подправить/написать подробнее. Понимаю что для post запроса нужные и другие данные, но я просто не представляю какие и от куда их брать. Буду благодарен если напишите код решения проблемы
ОБНОВЛЕНО
Капчу решал через сервис anti-captcha.com/ следующим способом:

```
            site_key = '322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460'

            solver = hCaptchaProxyless()
            solver.set_verbose(1)
            solver.set_key('KEY')  # Наш API ключ от сервиса для решения капч
            #solver.set_website_url(f'{iframe_rambler}')  
            solver.set_website_url(f'https://id.rambler.ru/account/change-password')  
            solver.set_website_key(f'{site_key}')  # Ключ сайта рамблер

            g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
            if g_response != 0:
                print("g-response: " + g_response)

            else:
                print("task finished with error " + solver.error_code)
```

Спустя 5-15 секунд в переменную g_response приходит токен решенной капчи

Comment: Получилось решить? или больше не занимался этим вопросом?

Comment: @Minor Забил и перешел на другой сервис где нет такой капчи. Но в ответе ниже про аддон для firefox-a предоставлено рабочее решение, проверил на другом ресурсе

Answer (score 1):

тебе нужно не просто пост запрос выполнить. надо сначала реально капчу решить и получить токен решения. например используя сервисы для распознавания. Потом нужно полученный токен поместить в скрытые элементы h-captcha-response и g-recaptcha-response и отправить форму (или вызвать callback функцию, зависит от страницы). процесс решения будет описан в документации к сервису.

также новая hCaptcha прячет коллбек функцию. У меня есть дополнение которое эту коллбек функцию вытаскивает. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-helper/

после его установки; на странице, где есть hCaptcha, будет доступен объект

```
let widgetInfo = {
    captchaType: "hcaptcha",
    widgetId: 0,
    containerId: container,
    sitekey: opts.sitekey,
    callback: opts.callback,
};
```

ну и может быть поможет вот это https://alexandrsokolov-41020.medium.com/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-hcaptcha-9eebf2ee3c5a

Comment: Решение капчи имеется, сейчас обновлю пост с примером кода, решал через anti-captcha.com/, токен выводило

Comment: вот. отлично. первый шаг готов. но его нужно подтюнить, тебе обязательно надо передать на сервер распознавания прокси и юзер агент, так как куки выдаваемые капчей будут привязаны к этим параметрам. ну а "токен решенной капчи" нужно инсертить по textarea и выполнять какой-то action

Comment: Понял суть но не осознал как воплотить в действие.... 
Можете какой нибудь пример написать? (с юзерагентом все ясно, сделаю, но вот выполнять action....)

Comment: про action я имел ввиду нажать кнопку, если это форма какая-то, или выполнить callback функцию если это страница валидации браузера.